# Laravel auth0 users search returns full list

Tags: php, laravel, auth0

I have the following piece of code:

```
$auth0Api = new Management(env('AuthToken'), env('Auth0Domain'));    
$user = $auth0Api->users->search([ "user_id" => "google-oauth2|103122844576645532487"]);
```

The point of this is to return a single user with the given `id`

However, whenever I call this I get the full list of my users.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Auth0 search](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/user-search) they use [Lucene Query Syntax](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html), which means an Auth0 search query for `google-oauth2 user with the id of 103122844576645532487` should look like this:

```
identities.provider:"google-oauth2" AND user_id:"103122844576645532487"
```

The PHP SDK you are using assembles the request to the API for you under the hood based on key/values provided through a `withParam` method. The `search` method you are using takes your parameters (`['user_id' => '...']`) and passes them to `withParam`, then your request is executed.

Your `search([...])` code is translating into the following API request:

```
/api/v2/users?user_id="google-oauth2|10312284457664553248"
```

However, the API does not support a `user_id` parameter on the `api/v2/users` endpoint and your request is being executed as  `api/v2/users`, which is the request to return all users. This is why you're receiving all of your users: you are not (correctly) passing a search query.

You need to specifically include the `q` (query) parameter when building your search, and that parameter should equal a valid Lucene Query.

```
$auth0Api->users->search([
    'q' => 'identities.provider:"google-oauth2" AND user_id:"103122844576645532487"'
]);
```

This will search for users where their identity provider is `google-oauth2` and their user_id is `103122844576645532487`.

You can read the documentation for [the `api/v2/users` method here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users).

Comment: A side note that doesn't belong in this answer but a point I wanted to make: I am baffled that their SDK functions this way. They expose a `search` method that *doesn't* build a search query. That's poor design and no wonder it's leading to confusion.